# how can I refactor code using Binding from view to viewmodel

Tags: c#

I have some simple if statements linked to Ellipse. Code works fine but i am re-useing alot of the same code over any over (if statments).

I wanted to know if this can be do without re-using all the same code? maybeing having a single 'Binding' in my view page

View: I have 4 ellipse and binding them to viewmodel

```
                <Ellipse Fill="{Binding EllipseFill1}" />
                <Ellipse Fill="{Binding EllipseFill2}" />
                <Ellipse Fill="{Binding EllipseFill3}" />
                <Ellipse Fill="{Binding EllipseFill4}"  />
```

ViewModel: here I am setting Ellipse Fill based on how many ints are in List.

```
   List<int> CreatePin = new List<int>();
   void SetColorPin()
    {
        if (CreatePin.Count == 0)
        {
            EllipseFill1 = Brush.Transparent;
            EllipseFill2 = Brush.Transparent;
            EllipseFill3 = Brush.Transparent;
            EllipseFill4 = Brush.Transparent;
        }
        if (CreatePin.Count == 1) 
        { 
            EllipseFill1 = Brush.White;
            EllipseFill2 = Brush.Transparent;
            EllipseFill3 = Brush.Transparent;
            EllipseFill4 = Brush.Transparent;
        }
        if (CreatePin.Count == 2) {
            EllipseFill1 = Brush.White;
            EllipseFill2 = Brush.White;
            EllipseFill3 = Brush.Transparent;
            EllipseFill4 = Brush.Transparent;
        }
        if (CreatePin.Count == 3) {
            EllipseFill1 = Brush.White;
            EllipseFill2 = Brush.White;
            EllipseFill3 = Brush.White;
            EllipseFill4 = Brush.Transparent;
        }
        if (CreatePin.Count == 4) {
            EllipseFill1 = Brush.White;
            EllipseFill2 = Brush.White;
            EllipseFill3 = Brush.White;
            EllipseFill4 = Brush.White;
        }
    }


    // Bind to UI - testLabel
    private Brush ellipseFill1;
    public Brush EllipseFill1
    {
        get { return ellipseFill1; }
        set
        {
            if (value == ellipseFill1)
                return;

            ellipseFill1 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // Bind to UI - testLabel
    private Brush ellipseFill2;
    public Brush EllipseFill2
    {
        get { return ellipseFill2; }
        set
        {
            if (value == ellipseFill2)
                return;

            ellipseFill2 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // Bind to UI - testLabel
    private Brush ellipseFill3;
    public Brush EllipseFill3
    {
        get { return ellipseFill3; }
        set
        {
            if (value == ellipseFill3)
                return;

            ellipseFill3 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    // Bind to UI - testLabel
    private Brush ellipseFill4;
    public Brush EllipseFill4
    {
        get { return ellipseFill4; }
        set
        {
            if (value == ellipseFill4)
                return;

            ellipseFill4 = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me

view

```
          <Ellipse Fill="{Binding EllipseFill1}" />
            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding EllipseFill2}" />
            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding EllipseFill3}" />
            <Ellipse Fill="{Binding EllipseFill4}"  />
```

viewmodel

```
      EllipseFill1 = helperCLass.SetColorPin(CreatePin, Brush.White, 1);
        EllipseFill2 = SetColorPin(CreatePin, Brush.White, 2);
        EllipseFill3 = SetColorPin(CreatePin, Brush.White, 3);
        EllipseFill4 = SetColorPin(CreatePin, Brush.White, 4);

    public Brush SetColorPin(List<int> valueList, Brush value, int PinNumber)
    {
        return (valueList.Count < PinNumber) ? Brush.Transparent : value;
    }
```

Comment: this is simple and clean

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce the amount of repetition you can do this:

```
EllipseFill1 = CreatePin.Count > 0 ? Brush.White : Brush.Transparent;
EllipseFill2 = CreatePin.Count > 1 ? Brush.White : Brush.Transparent;
EllipseFill3 = CreatePin.Count > 2 ? Brush.White : Brush.Transparent;
EllipseFill4 = CreatePin.Count > 3 ? Brush.White : Brush.Transparent;
```

The number of checks is the same but there are fewer lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring isn't black and white. But I would do:

```
//Define the collection you want to change somewhere.
private readonly Elipse[] Elipses =  
{
    EllipseFill1,
    EllipseFill2,
    EllipseFill3,
    EllipseFill4
}

void SetColorPin()
{
    //You could also go from bottom to top, when that might be less readable
    for (int i = 0; i < Elipses.Length; i++) 
    {
        Elipses[i] = Brush.Transparant;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < CreatePin.Count; i++)
    {
        Elipses[i] = Brush.White;
    }
}
```

When you add an Elipse, it automatically gets changed too.

Both the Transparant and White could be put in a constant if you think it might change.

For setting the transparant Elipses (first for-loop) this could also be done. The result is that there are fewer loops, but might be less readable:

```
for (int i = Elipses.Length-1; i >= CreatePin.Count; i--) 
{
    Elipses[i] = Brush.Transparant;
}
```